# Java Map Reduce Read from Different Format - Avro, Textfile

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a few Hive tables where some of them are in Avro format and some of them are in plain textfile. The schemas are slightly different but all contains certain attributes that I need.

I am planning to write a map reduce job process the data. The question is that I am trying to avoid tons of separate jobs and trying to simplify the process as much as possible. Finger crossed that I only need to write one job.

Is there any example of showing how to read different format of inputs in one mapper.

Say for example, I have a hdfs path I know in AVRO, and I also have another hdfs path where the data is in plain text file.

```
// Pseudo code
mapper (Paths){
    for(Path in Paths){
        if Path.containsAvro() {
            ... read as avro
        } else {
            ... read as textfile
        }
        ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two different mappers, one for each format, for the same job.  The mappers can each read their own format of data but must all write the same format of data.  Use something like this to configure:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(path_to_data_with_format_1), SomeInputFormat.class, ReadFormatOneMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(path_to_data_with_format_2), SomeOtherInputFormat.class, ReadFormatTwoMapper.class);
```

Of course, SomeInputFormat and SomeOtherInputFormat aren't real input format classes.  In this example the two mapper classes would output key/value pairs with the same kay/value types and the reducer, if you have one, would get the data from both mappers.